# ios - button out of cellView don't get touch event

Tags: ios, tableview, interaction

I've a table view, and I'm bringing the middle cellView to the front. This view has a sub view that is displayed above it, overlapping the previous cell. When I tap this sub view, the button in it doesn't get the touch event. Instead, the previous cell that is displayed below the button get the cell selection.

Wether I set is UserInteractionEnable to true or false for the cell underneath doesn't change the behavior.

```
----------------------> z-index

cell 1
|
|             button within cell 2
|    cell 2      |
        |
        |
        |
```

How can I get button to get touch event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `UITableViewCell` subclass you should override `pointInside` with something like:

```
    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool
    {
        if self.isSelected
        {
           return self.button.frame.contains(point) || self.frame.contains(point)
        }
        return super.point(inside: point, with: event)
    }
```

Comment: Excellent thanks. It looks safer to return `super.point` instead of `self.frame.contains`, but they probably do the same.